# What is the connection between Ashe's arrow travel distance and the stun duration?

Tags: league-of-legends

When you used to throw a spear with Nidalee and you walked away, it did more damage because of the distance you build in that time. Riot changed that and now you throw the spear and the position you started the throw from is used, rather than your position when it hit.

Is the same thing true of Ashe's ult? Does the stun duration depend on the distance between you and your target when it hits the enemy or when you initially fire it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Enchanted Crystal Arrow:**

`Active: Ashe fires a giant arrow in a straight line. If it hits an enemy champion, it will deal magic damage and stun that champion for 1-3.5 second(s), based on the distance the arrow traveled.`

As the description from Ashe's ultimate says `[...] based on the distance the arrow traveled.`. This means, that the stun duration is calculated from the position *where you used the ability*, because after firing the arrow, your movement won't affect the distance the arrow travels.

This also adds up with the new description of Nida's Q:

**Javelin Toss:**

`Active: Nidalee hurls her javelin forward in a line, dealing magic damage to the first enemy it hits. After having traveled 525 units, the javelin's damage will start rapidly increasing. The damage modifier is capped at 250% at maximum range.`

Here it also states the damage multiplier is calculated from the spear *travelling a certain distance*. This adds up, with the fact that the actualy position of your champion when your spear hits *does not matter*.

Source: [lolwiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ashe)

Comment: Are there any numbers that anyone knows associated with the damage calculation?

Comment: It's most probably increasing linearly. So at 525 units, the damage modifier is 100%, then it goes up the same number of percentage points per unit travelled until it reaches max range, where the damage modifier will be 250%. For example, if the max range was 675, it would go up by 1% per unit travelled beyond 525, so at 600 units, it would be at 175%.

Comment: Follow up question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159608/what-is-the-distance-required-for-ashes-ulti-to-stun-for-maximum-duration