# What is the distance required for Ashe's ulti to stun for maximum duration?

Tags: league-of-legends

As Ashe's ulti is described, a max of 3.5 second stun is possible. But how far must the arrow have travelled for the duration to be this long?

> Active: Ashe fires a giant arrow in a straight line. If it hits an
>   enemy champion, it will deal magic damage and stun that champion for
>   1-3.5 second(s), based on the distance the arrow traveled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ashe), the maximum stun duration is achieved at 2800 range.

Comment: In the link supplied, the range is stated in a tool-tip if you hover your mouse over the duration in the skill description. (For comparison Caitlyn's max ranked ulti is 3000 range)